# General Philosophy StackExchange Questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, tags, new-users, user-accounts

I study computer science and intend to work in that, so I'm more frequently on anything closely related to StackOverflow, which might be more core to StackExchange than this particular area of the site (not to offend anyone here, but from a number of users perspective it's probably true). This is the least technical StackExchange site I've posted in probably, so that's my place in it. Just wondering how it differs significantly from StackOverflow on a few points if at all as I'm also new to Philosophy StackExchange.

1. I get tagging questions, but maybe philosophy has fewer tags to the point I'm not sure what tags are good to use here. Not a professional philosopher, but I want to be sure anyone knowledgeable at least understands my tag usage as maybe I'm not sure what people use where here.
2. **Answered my own question on this so I'm good on this one.** Reputation needed to create tags here.

Thanks in advance for clarifying the usage of Philosophy StackExchange site. I think StackOverflow probably just needs more tags for different programming languages, so I'm just probably used to choosing between more tags there. Seems like I would need to add tags to affect that though.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first question. Are you asking if you're using tags correctly?

Comment: What tags are you curious/doubtful about...?

Comment: Maybe I'm tired but I can't really figure out what this post is asking.

Comment: My understanding of this question is that you are asking how tags on this SE site work compared to stackoverflow. To be honest, the tags aren't the most important part of asking a good question. Nobody is going to vote to close your question because you used the wrong tag or didn't include a relevant one, so you shouldn't worry that much about them, there are a large amount of active users who will happily edit your questions to make sure the right tags are used.The other aspects of a good question (clarity, proof of effort in finding an answer, context, etc.) are much more important.

Comment: Although I should say, that doesn't mean don't make an effort in tagging your questions. All I am saying is that you should use the tag you think is relevant and if there is an issue someone will probably be along to help you out. The most important part of asking a good question is clarity of purpose.

Comment: @Not_Here Thanks for your thorough answer. Agreed that content is also important in this. At the end of the day it's a Q&A site so I get that it's also on me to write the question. It would probably jump out to me that someone didn't get tags if I get the question in StackOverflow for instance, but it's what I know vs what I might not know. I wasn't aware if y'all have a different system for good tags here or something. I take it Philosophy is a newer SE site though so I figured ask.

Comment: To my knowledge the phil.se started in around 2011, so I wouldn't really say that its 'new' although it did graduate last year. Anyway, the tags for philosophy are similar to how they work for a math or physics or some other academic discipline. There are specific topics and specific branches of philosophy (e.g. epistemology, metaphysics, truth, etc) and a large amount of those concepts are tags. Similarly to how you would tag your question with calculus if you were asking a question about derivatives on math.se, you should tag your question with epistemology if you are asking about knowledge.